# Display google photos embed as a grid on joomla website (publicalbum.org)

Tags: joomla-3.x, extensions, google

I will upload a pretty large amount of photos on my website and I don't want to overload the server.

I was thinking it might be a good idea to upload the images to google photos and embed them on the website.

I found [a page that creates javascript embed code](https://www.publicalbum.org/blog/embedding-google-photos-albums), but it is not very customizable. The application displays the gallery as a slideshow, which is not the most practical if you have a large number of photos.

Is it possible to change photo display to a grid?

Answer (score 2):

There are at least a few gallery extensions that integrate with Google Photos such as:

- Event Gallery https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/event-gallery
- Ozio Gallery https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/ozio-gallery
- Phoca Gallery https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/phoca-gallery